# Extract the username with beautifulsoup from Facebook

Tags: python, facebook, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the username from Facebook posts without API. I've already succeeded in extraction the timestamp, but the same algorithm is not working with the username.
As input I have a list of links like these:

https://www.facebook.com/barackobama/photos/a.10155401589571749/10156901908101749/?type=3&theater

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=391679854902607&set=gm.325851774772841&type=1&theater

https://www.facebook.com/FisherHouse/photos/pcb.10157433176029134/10157433170239134/?type=3&theater

I've already tried searching with pageTitle, but it is not working as expected because there are many unuseful  information.
`facebook = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
 facebookusername = str (facebook.select('[id="pageTitle"]'))`

My code now is:

```
req = requests.get(url)
facebook = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
divs = facebook.find_all('div', class_="_title")
for iteration in range (len(divs)):
   if 'title' in str(divs[iteration]):
       print (divs[iteration])
```

I need only the username as output.

Comment: Facebook does not allow you to scrape them. Use the API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As WizKid said, you should use the API. But to give you an answer: The name of the page seems to be nested within the h5-title. Extract the h5 first and then get the name.

```
x = facebook.find('h5')
title = x.find('a').getText()
```

I can't try it at the moment but that should do the trick.